# How can I get the real underlying database connection from an existing QueryRunner in TypeORM?

Tags: mysql, node.js, typeorm

I have an instance of `QueryRunner` and I need to fetch the real underlying database connection established through the driver, in this case mysqljs.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up reading through the TypeORMs code and happens that I had only to call the `QueryRunner#connect()` again and it will return the already established connection.

https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/src/driver/mysql/MysqlQueryRunner.ts

Here is the relevant documentation in source code:

```
   /**
     * Creates/uses database connection from the connection pool to perform further operations.
     * Returns obtained database connection.
     */
    connect(): Promise<any> {
        if (this.databaseConnection)
            return Promise.resolve(this.databaseConnection);
```